# Wait to start next method or thread until a background thread ends in windows form application with C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am creating a background thread in a windows form application to do some process that takes time while handling huge data. However, I still want some other methods or processes to wait until this thread finishes its work.

To create a background thread, I used below inline code.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateXml2Resx(account, features, codes, outputDir));
```

So once, this process of generating all *.resx files from xml data is done, I want my application to proceed further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the other methods in a `Task.ContinueWith()` callback, which will only run after the first task finishes.

If you want that to run in the UI thread, pass `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

Comment: +1 for 'don't wait - signal/message completion later and deal with it when it happens'.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Nice. Thanks a lot. Now, I will play with it more and try to customize my application. Main advantage that it preserves the purpose of multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

Use Thread.Join : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this one is also a possible solution to my problem. Frankly, I do not understand the whole logic of threading yet. Sure will read more about it.

Comment: No, it would not. Sometimes you have many operations to do that you can do simultaneously, you put them in several threads, and then you wait for all of them to finish before proceeding. If you put them all in 1 thread it takes much longer. I don't see what's inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think Task.Wait does the trick http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using the thread in the first place.